# RadGrid vs GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am migrating gridview to RadGrid. I am working on updating my RadGrid rows where I am getting some issues.

I updating Clarify Account Nbr, site id, Quote ID columns in "Inplace" editmode. Lets say before update my values are 200, 300, 400 for columns  Clarify Account Nbr, site id, Quote ID. When i click edit button and change the values to 111, 222, 333. when I am debugging my code and trying to see the textbox.text values  It is showing the old values(200, 300, 400) not the new values (111, 222, 333). ( I hope you guys are understand my problem). Where I am doing wrong. Please help me.

I saw this link but no use.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-vs-gridview.aspx

In the below code if you see

```
string ClarifyAccountNbr = (editedItem["Clarify Account Nbr"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
string SiteID = (editedItem["Site ID"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
string QuoteID = (editedItem["Quote ID"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
```

when I am debugging and pointing to ClarifyAccountNbr, SiteID, QuoteID I am getting older values not new values.( before updating)

Here is my code:

.aspx:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rg200" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="30"
Height="550px" OnNeedDataSource="rg200_NeedDataSource" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True"
AllowSorting="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" EnableHeaderContextMenu="True"
GridLines="None" EnableHeaderContextFilterMenu="True" AllowMultiRowEdit="True"
AllowFilteringByColumn="True" OnPreRender="rg200_PreRender" OnItemCreated="rg200_ItemCreated"
EnableViewState="False" OnUpdateCommand="rg200_UpdateCommand">
    <HeaderStyle Height="20px" BackColor="#004000" Font-Size="8pt" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"
        HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" />
    <ExportSettings IgnorePaging="true" ExportOnlyData="true">
        <Pdf AllowModify="false" AllowPrinting="true" PageBottomMargin="" PageFooterMargin=""
            PageHeaderMargin="" PageHeight="11in" PageLeftMargin="" PageRightMargin="" PageTopMargin=""
            PageWidth="14in" />
    </ExportSettings>
    <MasterTableView GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="orderId" CommandItemDisplay="Top"
        EditMode="InPlace">
        <CommandItemSettings ShowExportToWordButton="true" ShowExportToExcelButton="true"
            ShowExportToCsvButton="true" ShowExportToPdfButton="true" ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" />
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName="ClientSelectColumn" HeaderStyle-Width="3%"
                ItemStyle-Width="3%">
                <HeaderStyle Width="3%"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemStyle Width="3%"></ItemStyle>
            </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="sId" HeaderText="sId" DataField="sId" Visible="false">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="orderId" HeaderText="orderId" DataField="orderId">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Customer Name" HeaderText="Customer Name" DataField="Customer Name"
                ReadOnly="true">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Market Name" HeaderText="Market Name" DataField="Market Name"
                ReadOnly="true">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="LOB" HeaderText="LOB" DataField="LOB" ReadOnly="true">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Headend Name" HeaderText="Headend Name" DataField="Headend Name"
                ReadOnly="true">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Project Name" HeaderText="Project Name" DataField="Project Name"
                ReadOnly="true">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Site Name" HeaderText="Site Name" DataField="Site Name"
                ReadOnly="true">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Task Status" HeaderText="Task Status" DataField="Task Status"
                ReadOnly="true">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <%--<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Clarify Account Nbr" HeaderText="Clarify Account Nbr"
                DataField="Clarify Account Nbr">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblClarifyAccountNbr" Text='<%# Eval("Clarify Account Nbr") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtClarifyAccountNbr" Text='<%# Eval("Clarify Account Nbr") %>'
                        runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>--%>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Clarify Account Nbr" HeaderText="Clarify Account Nbr"
                DataField="Clarify Account Nbr">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Site ID" HeaderText="Site ID" DataField="Site ID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Quote ID" HeaderText="Quote ID" DataField="Quote ID">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn UniqueName="EDP Created?" HeaderText="EDP Created?" DataField="EDP Created?">
            </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="ECC200">
            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
        </Columns>
        <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True"></PagerStyle>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" ReorderColumnsOnClient="false" AllowDragToGroup="false"
        AllowColumnsReorder="True">
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="true" EnableVirtualScrollPaging="false" UseStaticHeaders="true" />
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"></Selecting>
        <Resizing AllowRowResize="true" AllowColumnResize="True" EnableRealTimeResize="True"
            ResizeGridOnColumnResize="False"></Resizing>
        <%--<ClientEvents OnGridCreated="GridCreated" OnCommand="GridCommand" />--%>
    </ClientSettings>
    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" AlwaysVisible="true"></PagerStyle>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

.cs file:

```
public partial class Tak200 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["SearchRes"] = null;
                if (Session["TaskName"] != null)
                    lblTskName.Text = Session["TaskName"].ToString();
                Session["FilColms"] = null;
                Session["SortExp"] = null;
                Session["FilExp"] = null;
                Session["ViewAll"] = null;
                BindGrid();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();

            clsSearch_BL clsObj = new clsSearch_BL();
            clsObj.TaskID = (string)Session["TaskID"];
            clsObj.CustName = (string)Session["CustName"];
            clsObj.MarketName = (string)Session["MarketName"];
            clsObj.HeadendName = (string)Session["HeadendName"];
            clsObj.SiteName = (string)Session["SiteName"];
            clsObj.TaskStatus = (string)Session["TaskStatus"];
            clsObj.OrdType = (string)Session["OrdType"];
            clsObj.OrdStatus = (string)Session["OrdStatus"];
            clsObj.ProName = (string)Session["ProName"];
            clsObj.LOC = (string)Session["LOC"];
            clsObj.QuoteID = (string)Session["QuoteID"];
            clsObj.CMNumber = (string)Session["CMNumber"];

            if (Session["SearchRes"] == null)
            {
                dsResult = clsObj.getSearchResults_BL(clsObj);
                Session["SearchRes"] = dsResult;
            }
            else
                dsResult = (DataSet)Session["SearchRes"];

            DataView dataView = dsResult.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            rg200.DataSource = dsResult;
            //rg200.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    protected void rg200_NeedDataSource(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }

    protected void rg200_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rg200.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("RowIndicator").Display = false;

    }

    protected void rg200_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridPagerItem)
        {
            RadComboBox combo = (e.Item as GridPagerItem).FindControl("PageSizeComboBox") as RadComboBox;

            // The number of items shown when all is selected 
            int allRowsCount = int.MaxValue;

            // Remove duplicates 
            RadComboBoxItem duplicate = combo.Items.FindItemByValue(allRowsCount.ToString());
            if (duplicate != null)
            {
                duplicate.Remove();
            }

            // Create a new item for showing all 
            RadComboBoxItem item = new RadComboBoxItem("All", allRowsCount.ToString());
            item.Attributes.Add("ownerTableViewId", e.Item.OwnerTableView.ClientID);
            combo.Items.Add(item);

            // Set the current pagesize as the selected value 
            combo.Items.FindItemByValue(rg200.PageSize.ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
    }

    protected void rg200_UpdateCommand(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int intTskID = Convert.ToInt16(Session["TaskID"]);


        GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
        //Get the primary key value using the DataKeyValue.      
        string Id = editedItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[editedItem.ItemIndex]["orderId"].ToString();
        //Access the textbox from the edit form template and store the values in string variables.
        string ClarifyAccountNbr = (editedItem["Clarify Account Nbr"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string SiteID = (editedItem["Site ID"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
        string QuoteID = (editedItem["Quote ID"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

The bullet-proof approach is to fetch the new data from the column editors as presented on this Telerik demo:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/editmodes/defaultcs.aspx

Hope this helps.

Dick